# Select one row with priority for value

Tags: mysql, sql

Ello!

I'm trying to select a single row with either 'w', 'e' or 's' and an unique GUID. 'e' has a the highest priority so when a GUID contains that that line should be selected. 'w' the 2nd highest priority, so when there is no other than 's' 'w' should be selected. Along with the entire row data.

I've tried to use the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE GUID IN (SELECT DISTINCT GUID FROM TABLENAME ) 
AND (CATEGORY='S' OR CATEGORY='E' OR CATEGORY='W')
```

Is there anyway how I can do what I'm describing? I've been trying to use different ways of using distinct and other methods but it's still giving me more than one line per GUID.

Group by hasn't worked either. Since I get an error when I add that.

**EDIT: Added Images**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zgeF.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select guid, min(priority) from
(SELECT *, 
 case when category = 'E' then 1
      when category = 'W' then 2
      when category = 'S' then 3 
 end as priority 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE CATEGORY in ('S','E','W') ) a
```

The inner query assigns priority to the `category` column as per the question. In the outer query you select from whichever category has the highest priority. Also include all the other columns you need in the outer `select`.

Edit: The method above isn't robust as you can't use the calculated `priority` column to select the corresponding category per guid. 
 Hence, Another approach is to use `union`.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE CATEGORY = 'E'
union
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE CATEGORY = 'W' 
and guid not in (select guid from tablename where category ='E')
union
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE CATEGORY = 'S'
and guid not in(select guid from tablename where category in ('E','W'))
```

The first query selects all rows where category is `E`. The second query selects all rows whose category is `W` and whose guid wasn't selected before. The third query selects all rows whose category is `S` and whose guid wasn't selected in the previous two queries. 
`UNION` ing  all the queries should give you the results you need.
Try the SQL fiddle with dummy data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07c0d/1

Comment: Since the op asked for a single line i think if you add the LIMIT 1 on your query it would be perfect. +1 anyway

Comment: `max` always selects one row per guid..or do i still need `limit 1`?

Comment: The LIMIT 1 is not needed since I'd still like to have all unique GUIDs. This seems to work. But how can I add other collums?

Comment: Well since the GUID is unique you are right there is no need for LIMIT 1 :)

Comment: I do not really understand the single a before group by. Could someone explain that please?

Comment: `a` is an alias for the inner query. You can name whatever you want. It is just that you can reference the column with `a.guid` or `max(a.priority)`. It would be useful when you need to `join` on another table.

Comment: is that column in the inner table you are selecting from?

Comment: Seems not to be working 100%. A couple of GUID's have 'E' as CATEGORY and still get assigned a 3 for 'S'.

Comment: modified it..it should be `min(priority)` as we are ranking them 1 as the highest,  2 as the next highest..

Comment: Can't really get to add columns myself. But your answer is marked correct again! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you show the table structure and specifythe columns you need, i can add it

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3zgeF.png is the content of one GUID. Other GUIDs have the same but different data

Comment: Yes, please if that's possible.

Comment: modified it..see if you get the expected results

Comment: I get the following error: The text, ntext, and image datatypes cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: modified it again..try it

Comment: @MaxNijholt . . . Does this *really* answer your question?  It doesn't return a single row per guid?

Comment: @GordonLinoff..thanks for pointing it out. I missed the trick. Modified the query.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to get the appropriate category for each guid and then `join` back.  Another is a series of `union all`s.  The latter is possibly more efficient, because you don't have very many options to prioritize:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where category = 'e'
union all
select t.*
from tablename t
where category = 'w' and
      not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.category in ('e') and t2.guid  = t.guid
                 ) 
union all
select t.*
from tablename t
where category = 's' and
      not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.category in ('e', 'w') and t2.guid  = t.guid
                 ) ;
```

For performance, you want an index on `category` and `guid, category`.

Comment: How is that giving a single row?

Comment: @JorgeCampos . . . It fetches a single row for each `guid`, based on the priority.